# Passing a path on a function (Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression)

Tags: syntax, parameters, path, expression

today I'm struggling with an "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:".
I would pass a path to a function that preload images but when I'm going to call it, I get the error:

```
preLoader('img/realizzazione-impianti-fotovoltaici-header.png');
```

This is the function:

```
var preLoader = function (arrayOfImages){
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        //$('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
        cacheImage.src = this;
        cacheImg.push(cacheImage);
        });//each

    }//preLoader
```